# Get List Item ID from NewForm.aspx

Tags: jquery, custom-list, list-form

SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Version

I have a Custom List and i have created a copy of NewForm.aspx and saved it as CustomNewForm.aspx. When I save the item i want to get the saved items ID and redirect the user to EditForm.aspx.

I used this article and I was able to redirect to EditForm but i'm not sure about the method used to get the Saved Item ID.
http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/

I also tried SPServices library but its not working or the value is returned as 0.
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPRedirectWithID&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Could you edit the first link to be more accurate. Currently it points to blog's category, which has many posts.

Comment: I fixed it for you

Comment: SPRedirectWithID should have worked. If you have time, could you please post the issue you had at http://SPServices.codeplex.com/discussions?

Comment: Hi Marc, Sure. I'll get back to you over the weekend with some screen shots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. I forgot to copy second script to edit form. Now its working as mentioned in the blog. http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/

1) The first script redirects to EditForm without ID

2) The second script on edit form check for ID and if its blank it retrieves the ID.

Apologies if I have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

this function returns the Item ID from URL:

```
function getProjectID()
{
    var urlParams;
    (window.onpopstate = function () {
        var match,
            pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        urlParams = {};
        while (match = search.exec(query))
           urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
    return urlParams;
}
```

So I guess you can only get the ID on Edit form

Comment: Hi Thiago, thanks for your response but I have fixed this issue. I forgot to copy second script to edit form. Now its working as mentioned in the blog.